# Can I disable Wi-fi on a Time Capsule?

Tags: wifi, time-capsule

Is it possible to disable Wi-fi on a Time Capsule device and use it only wired ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Airport Utility, select the time capsule; Airport tab; Wireless tab.  In the Wireless Mode dropdown, choose 'Off'.

[image]